# Aligning at top- Minipage

Tags: spacing, vertical-alignment, align, minipage

I referred the previous questions on aligning at the top when using a minipage. However, still could not solve the problem. I am guessing that there is some other problem in my code. The reduced version is given here. The exact problem is the text **Supervisor** should come at the top and then **....... Dr. J Braun** should be aligned accordingly (refer the picture). Can someone please point out the mistake in the code?

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{report}
\usepackage[byname]{smartref}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{setspace}

\makeatletter

\newenvironment{preliminary}%
{\pagestyle{plain}\pagenumbering{roman}}%
{\pagenumbering{arabic}}

% Set up page layout.
\setlength{\textheight}{9in} % Height of the main body of the text
\setlength{\topmargin}{-.5in} % .5" margin on top of page
\setlength{\headsep}{.5in}  % space between header and top of body
\addtolength{\headsep}{-\headheight} % See The LaTeX Companion, p 85
\setlength{\footskip}{.5in}  % space between footer and bottom of body
\setlength{\textwidth}{6.25in} % width of the body of the text
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{.25in} % 1.25" margin on the left for odd pages
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0in} % 1.25"  margin on the right for even pages

\raggedbottom

\def\normalspacing{1.25} % default line spacing

\newcommand\isdefinedsig[1]{%
  \edef\@tempa{#1}%
  \def\@tempb{}%
  \ifx\@tempa\@tempb
    \else \\ \dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\\{#1}\\
  \fi
}

\newcommand{\blank}{\hspace{-2mm}}
\newcommand{\super}{Dr. J Braun} %supervisor
\newcommand{\examo}{Dr. Aiham Naqvi}  %examining committee (up to four, if less leave blank)
\newcommand{\examt}{Dr. G. Kirloskar}
\newcommand{\examth}{Dr. D. Bing}
\newcommand{\examf}{Dr. A. Shing}
\newcommand{\department}{Civil and Environmental Engineering}
\newcommand{\degree}{Masters of Engineering Science}
\newcommand{\firstname}{Kumar}
\newcommand{\middlename}{Vishwas}
\newcommand{\lastname}{Om}
%\renewcommand{\author}[1]{\ifx\empty#1\else\gdef\@author{#1}\fi} 
\newcommand{\authorname}{{\firstname} {\middlename} {\lastname}}
\newcommand{\titl}{Design and implementation of Wind Turbine Foundations \protect\\ subjected to Combined Loading}
\newcommand{\thesisformat}{Monograph} %or Integrated Article
\newcommand{\gyear}{\number\year}

\newcommand{\makecert}{
   \setcounter{page}{1}
\vfill
\begin{center}
\large
THE UNIVERSITY OF XXXX XXXXXX\\
School of Graduate and Postdoctoral Studies\\
\vfill
\textbf{CERTIFICATE OF EXAMINATION}
\end{center}
\vfill
\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth} %tabular instead?

\begin{tabular}{l}
\underline{Supervisor:}\vspace{0.35in}
\isdefinedsig{\super}
\\
\end{tabular}
\vfill
\end{minipage}
%\hfill
\hspace{0.5in}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
\begin{tabular}{l}
\underline{Examiners:} \\\vspace{.5cm}
\isdefinedsig{\examo}\\
\isdefinedsig{\examt}\\
\isdefinedsig{\examth}\\
\isdefinedsig{\examf}
\end{tabular}
\vfill
\end{minipage}
\vfill
\end{table}
\vfill
\begin{center}
The thesis by \\ \vfill
\textbf{\firstname{} \middlename{} \underline{\lastname}}\\
\vfill
entitled:\\ \vfill
\textbf{\titl}\\\vfill
is accepted in partial fulfillment of the \\
requirements for the degree of\\
\degree\\
\end{center}
\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
\begin{tabular}{l}
\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\\
Date
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\hspace{0.5in}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\linewidth}
\begin{tabular}{l}
\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\\
Chair of the Thesis Examination \\Board
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\end{table}
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{preliminary}
\makecert
\end{preliminary}
\end{document}
```

The output I get is:
[image]

Can someone help? Additionally I am getting a warning of overfull \hbox by 40 pts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `table` and the two `minipage` environments aren't needed. Keep the two `tabular` environments, give each a `[t]` positioning specifier, and spread them out maximally by inserting an `\hfill` instruction between them.

```
....
\noindent
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l}
\underline{Supervisor:}\vspace{0.35in}
\isdefinedsig{\super}\\
\end{tabular}
\hfill
\begin{tabular}[t]{l@{}}
\underline{Examiners:} \\ \vspace{.5cm}
\isdefinedsig{\examo}\\
\isdefinedsig{\examt}\\
\isdefinedsig{\examth}\\
\isdefinedsig{\examf}
\end{tabular}
....
```

Comment: I added \begin{center} command before \begin{tabular} and the rest is okay.